# Match (Search, Letters)

Tags: search

I Have this function :

```
function! Test1()
     let myWord = "accroche-coeur"
     let cont1 = "-"
     if match(myWord,cont1)>=0  " if myWord contains cont1
         echo "Ok"
     else
         echo "No"
     endif
endfunction
```

I vould like make a function like that :

```
function! Test2()
   let cont1 = "irr"
   let myRep = "YesOrNo"
   silent! exe  '1,1 s/[A-Z-a-z-à-ù]*[A-Z-a-z-à-ù]/\=execute(if (search,cont1)>=0 then myRep="Yes" endif)'
   echo myRep
endfunction
```

Could you tell me please what I have to insert between the parenthesis of execute( ... ) for that returns "Yes" if my text contains cont1.

For example, if I have this text :

> Books are the m**irr**or of the soul.

This function has to return "Yes"

Comment: Bienvenue à [vi.se]! You might want to read `:help expr`; one if the constructs is a ternary conditional

Comment: Are you searching for that text `irr` in line 1 of your buffer? That's what it looks like from the `1,1` before the `s/...`. Can you be more specific in describing where exactly you want to search for that term?

Comment: In the line 1, for each word, I would like to know if it contains `irr`

Comment: Something like that :                                                                                                 while search ("[A-Z-a-zà-ù]*[A-Z-a-zà-ù]", 'W')
     if search = "mirror"
            echo "search"                                                                                                   endif
    endwhile